# SparkSubmitOperator raises “dag_id could not be found" errors when run

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

So I've got a Spark job to pull some domains from AWS, then three different jobs that each take said domains and extract various data from the sites. For some reason this workflow stalls at ImportS3CrawlData with the following error:

```
[2018-03-22 13:37:02,762] {models.py:1428} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): ImportCrawlJob> on 2018-03-22 13:37:00
[2018-03-22 13:37:02,763] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Running: ['bash', '-c', 'sudo -H -u hdfs airflow run dag_extract_jobs ImportCrawlJob 2018-03-22T13:37:00 --job_id 21 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/run_extract_jobs.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmpir3e3r32']
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,194] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-03-22 13:37:04,193] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,356] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-03-22 13:37:04,356] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow/dags/run_extract_jobs.py
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,451] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,451] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,451] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     args.func(args)
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,452] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 353, in run
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,452] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     dag = get_dag(args)
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,452] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 130, in get_dag
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,452] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask:     'parse.'.format(args.dag_id))
[2018-03-22 13:37:04,452] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: dag_extract_jobs. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
```

The code for run_extract_jobs.py can be found below, with sensitive/unnecessary bits removed.

```
# Parameters to initialize Spark:
access_id = Variable.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
bucket_name = 'cb-scrapinghub'
secret_key = Variable.get("AWS_SECRET_KEY")
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

DAG = DAG(
    dag_id='dag_extract_jobs',
    description='Run Extract Jobs',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2018, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
)

# Spark Job that runs ImportS3CrawlData:
importCrawlJob = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='ImportCrawlJob',
    ...
    run_as_user='hdfs',
    dag=DAG,
)

# Spark Job that runs ExtractAboutText:
extractAboutText = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='ExtractAboutText',
    ...
    run_as_user='hdfs',
    dag=DAG
)
extractAboutText.set_upstream(importCrawlJob)

# Spark Job that runs ExtractCompanyInfo:
extractCompanyInfo = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='ExtractCompanyInfo',
    ...
    run_as_user='hdfs',
    dag=DAG
)
extractCompanyInfo.set_upstream(importCrawlJob)

# Spark Job that runs ExtractWebPeople:
extractWebPeople = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='ExtractWebPeople',
    ...
    run_as_user='hdfs',
    dag=DAG
)
extractWebPeople.set_upstream(importCrawlJob)
```

I've made sure Airflow and Spark are both up to date. My dag folder is set up correctly. Airflow can run the tutorial files just fine.

I've been messing with this for days and am totally baffled. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It seems to me that the DAG itself has a problem. Can you list the DAG with `airflow list_dags` without a problem? If that works, what about `airflow list_tasks <dag-name>`?

Comment: Yup, both of those commands work just fine. That's why I'm baffled.

Comment: Is it related to `DAGS_FOLDER`? Did you write that or is this an unset variable? What happens if you execute exactly `sudo -H -u hdfs airflow run dag_extract_jobs ImportCrawlJob 2018-03-22T13:37:00 --job_id 21 --raw -sd DAGS_FOLDER/run_extract_jobs.py --cfg_path /tmp/tmpir3e3r32` in a shell on your own?

Comment: Didn't work with "--cfg_path /tmp/tmpir3e3r32", no such file or directory. I removed that variable entirely and got the "dag_id not found" error. Then I replaced "/tmp/tmpir3e3r32" with just the name of my config file, "airflow.cfg", and got this error message:

`File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: I do not understand why you exchanged a config path with a file name. It all seems to point to missing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't set the configuration parameters correctly.

Make sure to work through the first part of https://airflow.apache.org/configuration.html

Also in the `airflow.cfg` make sure that you have set `dags_folder` to a filepath. While doing that you can also check if other settings and other paths need to be set.